# how to setup nodejs code on server(cpanel)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpanel

I have installed node js and npm on server successfully.

Node server is running properly on live with below message:-

Sever listening at port 3000.

My client js is as below:-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script>
        var socket = io.connect( 'https://'+window.location.hostname+':3000' );
        socket.on( 'new_count_message', function( data ) {
            if(curkey == data.key)
            {
                $('#notif_audio')[0].play();
                $( "#action" ).html( data.new_count_message ).css('color', '#a94442');
            }
        });
```

Here I am adding my sever js code on asking:-

```
var socket  = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('https').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on( 'new_count_message', function( data ) {
    io.sockets.emit( 'new_count_message', { 
        new_count_message: data.new_count_message,
        key: data.key
    });
  });
});
```

Note:- This code is working fine on localhost.

But on live showing below error:-

> err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch

1) How to correct this?

2) How to use local script instead of cdn script?

Comment: Did you verify that the socket.io script loaded correctly in the browser? To be very sure, try this url `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>`.

Comment: yes I did, but I will also try now with the provided

Comment: But I have all files locally, then why this is not taking this, any idea?

Comment: On using suggested URL, no Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined error. But failed net::(ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSE) error on each request

Comment: As the OP knows the `/socket.io/socket.io.js` file is served from socket.io lib, its independent from express so requires no static setup. @DeepakDholiyan enable debug to see whats going on, set env var `process.env.DEBUG = "*"` before anthing else.

Comment: Also add the server code your using.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, I have added sever js code

Comment: are you sure its https?

Comment: wait, Let me fix one

Comment: Corrected, now this is showing err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch. Thanks I will check on this now

Comment: You should update your question to note the new error and how you came to it

Comment: @RobertMennell, Thanks. I updated as per suggestion

Comment: Please read this: https://medium.com/@sslsecurity/how-to-fix-err-ssl-version-or-cipher-mismatch-error-5447c30ac78a

Comment: Stop opening related questions and deleting them.

Comment: @Brad, did you read this question? I can delete a question if I want.

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan Yes, I read your question.  And by all means, delete what you want, but don't expect any useful help.  Stack Overflow isn't your own personal free consulting service.  It's a place where people ask questions, and then people answer questions for *everyone's benefit*.  There's no point if you just delete your question as soon as you figured out what the issue was.  Stop wasting everyone's time and effort spent on you.

Comment: @Brad, I know this and I am here for helping others. I delete last question because I think this is not a good question. I am sorry If I was wrong

Comment: @Brad, please remove down vote from this question because this is a good question and I really need help. Please do if possible

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan What makes you think I downvoted your question?

Comment: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch/#settings_saved

Answer (score -2):

You probably need to serve the folder statically. Assuming you're using express, you can use this after requiring express:

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
```